# Dividing a matrix by a matrix: Bartlett Correlation Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, matrix-inverse

Is there a library with the inverse function included?

I am currently working on a direction finding algorithm as part of a project. I am using the Bartlett Correlation. In the Bartlett correlation I will need to divide the numerator, which is already 3 matrix multiplications(including Hermitian Transposes), by the denominator which is the product of a matrix and its Hermitian Transpose.

I realize that in order to divide I use the inverse. I am just trying to save time and hoping that there is a library where the inverse is included. I have only found links to source code for finding the inverse. This is only a small portion of the project and I am hoping to save time.
I do have the rest of my code written, but, have not started with the division/inverse yet. So, I will not include that code.

Comment: what programing languae are you using? try more specifc tags to get more relevant people to view your question

Comment: If you are using either of FORTRAN, C or C++ I would recommend [LAPACK](http://www.netlib.org/lapack) (or CLAPACK for the latter two) but as Shai says, without knowing what language you're using an accurate answer may be impossible

Comment: The TNT C++ matrix and associated JAMA linear algebra libraries developed by [NIST](http://math.nist.gov) are worth a look.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest use an implementation of BLAS, they are generally very versatile language and platform wise and used for building LAPACK as well.